# Using the textarea helper in Rails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, helper

Why does this code show an error in text area?

```
<%= form_for(:ad, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field(:name) %>
  <%= f.text_area_tag(:text, "", :size => "50x10") %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 33):

The `FormHelper` method is [`text_area`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_area), not `text_area_tag`.

Use either of the following:

```
<%= f.text_area(:text, size: '50x10') %>
```

or:

```
<%= text_area_tag(:ad, :text, size: '50x10') %>
```

Comment: i have this problem <code>wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)</code>

Comment: @maria When used with the form builder, the method only accepts two arguments. See updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

The `f` variable that you are creating in the first line is a reference to your **FormBuilder**. By default it references `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` or you can create your own.

The FormBuilder helper for textareas is called `text_area`. FormBuilder helpers are smarter than regular HTML helpers. Rails models can be nested logically, and your forms can be written to reflect this; one of the primary things FormBuilder helpers do is keep track of how each particular field relates to your data model.

When you call `f.text_area`, since `f` is associated with a form named `:ad` and the field is named `:text` it will generate a field named `ad[text]`. This is a parameter convention that will be automatically parsed into a Hash on the server: `{ :ad => { :text => "value" } }` instead of a flat list of parameters. This is a huge convenience because if you have a Model named `Ad`, you can simply call `Ad.create(params[:ad])` and all the fields will be filled in correctly.

`text_area_tag` is the generic helper that isn't connected to a form automatically. You can still make it do the same things as `FormBuilder#text_area`, but you have to do it manually. This can be useful in situations that a FormBuilder helper isn't intended to cover.